# can't login to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, just loops back to login screen (with standard desktop environment)?

Tags: login

My `Ubuntu` is in a login loop, there show a guest account however I had previously set Ubuntu to log in automatically, is. Not go to login screen. Initially it was stuck as I had set `tightvncserver` to start with `rc-update` but now after removing a new problem arises. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix?

I should mention that it seems to login as the desktop wallpaper changes, and I can access icons in top right of screen.

**xsession errors:**

> CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
>
> ERROR:gsm-manager code should not be reached

Comment: yes I can log in via terminal

Comment: One solution commonly suggested for this is to run `unity --reset` from the terminal. Can you try that?